# How to record varying values for duplicated IDs

Tags: r, for-loop, duplicates

I do not want to remove the duplicates, I want to record instances where a particular variable is duplicated and contains varying values for other columns. What I have works, but it's too slow.

So we have a data frame:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

df_test <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,2,3,4),
                 "Group1" = c("Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green"),
                 "Group2" = c(2.5, 2.5, 3, 7, 5, 6),
                 "Group3" = c("X","X", "X", "Y", "Z", "X")
                 )

> df_test
  ID Group1 Group2 Group3
1  1    Red    2.5      X
2  1   Blue    2.5      X
3  1   Blue    3.0      X
4  2    Red    7.0      Y
5  3 Yellow    5.0      Z
6  4  Green    6.0      X
```

We want to record all instances where there is varying information. In this case for ID = 1, we have varying information for both Group1 and Group2. So we want output as follows.

```
> repeated_df_test
   ID Where_Repeated Values_Present
1:  1         Group1      Red, Blue
2:  1         Group2         2.5, 3
```

Right now this is how I have it. I want to make it more efficient. I'm not sure where to begin with that.

```
where_are_dupes_occuring <- function(d, idvar){
  #d = df
  #idvar = the id variable to use
  nm <- deparse(substitute(d)) #name to use in assignment
  
  dupes <- d[duplicated(d[[idvar]]), ] #find the duplicated IDs
  dupes <- d[d[[idvar]] %in% dupes[[idvar]], ] #get all rows where there are duplicates 
  d <- dupes[!duplicated(dupes), ] #remove complete duplicates 
  
  where_repeated_f <- list()
  for(id in levels(unique(as.factor(d[[idvar]])))){ #for each repeated id
    dx <- d[d[[idvar]] == id, ] #get just the ID
    where_repeated <- list()
    for(c in colnames(dx)){ #for each column in data
      uvals <- droplevels(unique(as.factor(dx[[c]]))) #get whats present
      if(length(uvals) > 1){ #if theres more than 1 value present
        values_present <- toString(uvals)
        df <- data.frame("ID" = id, "Where_Repeated" = c, "Values_Present" = values_present) #record the repeated values
        where_repeated[[c]] <- df
      }
    }
    where_repeated_df <- rbindlist(where_repeated)
    where_repeated_f[[id]] <- where_repeated_df
  }
  where_repeated_f_df <- rbindlist(where_repeated_f)
  nmf <- paste0("repeated_",nm)
  assign(nmf, where_repeated_f_df, envir = .GlobalEnv) 
}

where_are_dupes_occuring(df_test, "ID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
subset(
  melt(
    setDT(df_test)[
      ,
      lapply(.SD, function(x) list(unique(x))), ID
    ],
    id.var = "ID",
    value.name = "Values_Present",
    variable.name = "Where_Repeated"
  ), lengths(Values_Present) > 1
)
```

which gives

```
   ID Where_Repeated  Values_Present
1:  1          Group1      Red, Blue
2:  1          Group2         2.5, 3
```

Comment: I apologize - I am having real trouble coming up with sample data that is representative in size and structure of my own. but using a sample of that with only 8k records - my time is running at  40 seconds and this is running at 3.8 mins

Comment: @mmb_rach I updated my answer. Could you try it again and check the speed?

Comment: My mistake. The critical component is that we must include this partition before we implement your function. ```dupes <- d[duplicated(d[[idvar]]), ] 
  dupes <- d[d[[idvar]] %in% dupes[[idvar]], ] 
  d <- dupes[!duplicated(dupes), ]```. This reduces the data going in. With that, this is now running about 43 seconds faster on the sample data than my function. And this version is faster than the previous